Changing color of segments from YOLO segment predicted images
I am working on an object detection project, detecting three types of objects in a set of images. This image shows a Sample of yolo segment model prediction model image.
The issue I have is that symbols detected in white. The color may be visible for some but it may not be so for others. Is there a way I can change this color? I am very new to python. I have already predicted the images of the whole set (amounting to 100,000 plus images).
I trained the YOLOv8 model using images where symbols of interests are labelled using LabelStudio. During the labelling, I used the colors for example red, blue and green. But somehow after obtaining the final YOLOv8 model (best.pt) and running the prediction, the detected symbols are in colors different than what was originally used. I have the following questions:

How can I change the white colors of the detected objects?

Is there a way to ensure the colors used in labelling on labelstudio retains in the predicted images?


import cv2
import numpy as np

# Define a function to replace the color of complete rectangular white bounding boxes
def replace_white_rectangles_with_green(image_path, output_path):
    # Read the image
    image = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    
    # Convert the image to grayscale for contour detection
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
    # Threshold the grayscale image to create a binary mask for white areas
    _, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 240, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    
    # Find contours to detect shapes
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    
    for contour in contours:
        # Approximate the contour to check if it forms a rectangle
        epsilon = 0.02 * cv2.arcLength(contour, True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour, epsilon, True)
        
        # Check if the contour has four edges (rectangle or square)
        if len(approx) == 4:
            # Verify if the shape is convex (to confirm it's a rectangle/square)
            if cv2.isContourConvex(approx):
                # Replace the white color of the bounding box with bright green
                cv2.drawContours(image, [contour], -1, (0, 255, 0), thickness=cv2.FILLED)
    
    # Save the modified image
    cv2.imwrite(output_path, image)

# Paths for input and output images
input_image_path = "path_to_your_image.jpg"  # Replace with your input image path
output_image_path = "path_to_save_modified_image.jpg"  # Replace with your desired output path

# Apply the function to the image
replace_white_rectangles_with_green(input_image_path, output_image_path)

print("The image has been processed, and white rectangular bounding boxes are replaced with green.")

I tried the above codes but somehow it only produces green boxes randomly or on original background that is originally white.

please show us what you mean
